# SQL Select rows from table where all joined rows match value

Tags: sql, join

I have **table A** that is linked to **table B**, which in turn is linked to **table C**.

I can only get from A to C through a key in B.

I must get all rows from A where ALL linked rows from C have C.value = 'Y'

I tried the following code but it already selects the row from A once a match has been found in one of the linked rows in C, not when ALL linked rows from C are matching C.value = 'Y'.

```
SELECT * FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
LEFT JOIN C ON B.ID2 = C.ID2
WHERE C.value = 'Y'
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking at that diagram, the 'N' value is in both B and C, no?

Comment: @JBKing I have updated the diagram and added a table example

Comment: Have you considered doing an exclusion query? Could be better at getting which rows to disqualify.

Comment: i dont under stand what you want the final output to be ?   if you want it to return things with a c.value ='y' then wouldnt id1 3 and 4 be returned?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @lookslikeanevo I want to select all rows from A where all the linked rows in C have value 'Y'. This is for an archive process. Rows from A can only be archived when all the linked rows in C have value 'Y'. Table B holds the link from A to all the related values in C.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The solution must be applicable to SQL server 2008 AND Oracle

Comment: @JBKing Perhaps this is the only solution, I was hoping there was a way to easily select the rows I required because the number of rows to disqualify are in greater quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query returns all the rows from A where all the linked rows from C have C.value 'Y' or where there is no link to B or to C available. Regards to JB King for the suggestion.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.ID1 
NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT A.ID1 FROM A 
  JOIN B ON A.ID1=B.ID1
  JOIN C ON B.ID2=C.ID2 WHERE C.value = 'N'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem now.. try this.  Might be a better way but this should work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
LEFT JOIN C ON B.ID2 = C.ID2
WHERE C.ID2 in (SELECT ID2 FROM C WHERE VALUE = 'N')
AND C.ID2 not in (SELECT ID2 FROM C WHERE VALUE <> 'N')
```

Comment: This gives the same result as my first attempt described in my question, it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: @Enrico what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `UNION ALL`. 
**Note:** Number of column in select statement should match

```
Select *
FROM (
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM C
)a
where value ='N'
```

Update:

```
 Select * From A
LEFT JOIN ( Select * FROM B INNER JOIN C 
               ON B.columnName = C.ColumnName 
                WHERE C.Value ='N') z
 ON z.columnName = A.ColumnName
```

Comment: The value field is only available in table C, table A,B,C have different columns.

Comment: which field is common on A, B  or B,C or A,C.

Comment: I have added a table example for clarification of my problem.

Comment: I tried your example, it gives the same result as in my first attempt, it does not produce the desired result.